# Range overlapping number and percentage calculation

Tags: perl

I want to calculate overlap number(#) and percentage (%) from a series of ranges values distributed in four different files initiated with a specific identifier(id) (like  NP_111111.4) . The initial list of ids are taken from file1.txt (starting file) and if the id matches with ids of other file, overlaps are calculated. Suppose my files are like this:

file1.txt

```
NP_111111.4: 1-9 12-20 30-41
YP_222222.2: 3-30 40-80
```

file2.txt

```
NP_111111.4: 1-6, 13-22, 31-35, 36-52
NP_414690.4: 360-367, 749-755
YP_222222.2: 19-24, 22-40
```

file3.txt

```
NP_418214.2: 1-133, 135-187, 195-272
YP_222222.2: 1-10
```

file4.txt

```
NP_418119.2 
YP_222222.2 GO:0016878, GO:0051108
NP_111111.4 GO:0005887
```

From these input file, I want to create a .csv or excel output with separate columns with header as:

```
id overlap_file1_file2(#) overlap_file1_file2(%) overlap_file1_file3(#) overlap_file1_file3(%) overlap_file1_file2_file3(#) overlap_file1_file2_file3(%) Go_Terms(File4)
```

I am learning perl and found a perl module "strictures" for this type of range comparison. I am calculating overlapping number and percentage from two ranges as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strictures;
use Number::Range;

my $seq1 = Number::Range->new(8..356); #Start and stop for file1.txt
my $seq2 = Number::Range->new(156..267); #Start and stop for file2.txt

my $overlap = 0;
my $sseq1 = $seq1->size;
my $percent = (($seq2->size * 100) / $seq1->size);

foreach my $int ($seq2->range) {
    if ( $seq1->inrange($int) ) {
    $overlap++;
    }
    else {
    next;
    }
}


print "Total size= $sseq1 Number overlapped= $overlap Percentage overlap= $percent \n";
```

But I could not find a way to match ids of (file1.txt) with other files to extract specific information and to print them in a output csv file.

Please help. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: `strictures` has nothing to do with your calculations. You probably got some example confused. `strictures` turns on `use strict` and `use warnings` for you, besides some other things. See https://metacpan.org/pod/strictures.

Comment: Is your data correct? Do all files except file1 have ranges separated by commas? Should file1 also have commas separating the ranges?

Comment: @Chris Charley - yes, the data are correct. As the files are themselves generated by different scripts, there are some differences of , and :

Comment: I think the number of overlaps is the elements in common to the files compared but I'm not sure how you want to get the percents. Ex. if there are 20 overlaps between file1 and file2 for an Id, what would you need for the denominator to get the percentage of the overlaps. The total elements in file1 for that Id or the total number of elements in file2 for the Id?

Comment: @Chris Charley, the file1 elements are used as denominators, you see, i want to calculate the percentage of all files in respect to file 1. Say if the file 1 range length is 30 and the overlap region of file2, file3 are 20 and 10, 30 will be the denominator in each case. and it has to be iterated for every range for an id in file 1

Comment: i mean u r right, the total elements of file1 will have to be used as denominator..; but in that case, it would be helpful if the range contents of each id are given in separate column before each overlap case, it would be easier to check the result by only looking at the output csv then

Comment: I would use [Set::IntSpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) not  Number::Range. Set::IntSpan will allow you to more easily determine set intersection (numbers in common between two sets of ranges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fragile solution in that it can only check 3 files for overlaps. If more files are involved, the code would need to be restructured. It uses Set::IntSpan to calculate the overlaps (and percent of overlaps.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Set::IntSpan;
use autodie;

my $file1 = 'file1';
my @files = qw/file2 file3/;

my %data;
my %ids;
open my $fh1, '<', $file1;

while (<$fh1>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $list) = split /:\s/;
    $ids{$id}++;
    $data{$file1}{$id} = Set::IntSpan->new(split ' ', $list);
}
close $fh1;

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my ($id, $list) = split /:\s/;
        next unless exists $ids{$id};

        $data{$file}{$id} = Set::IntSpan->new(split /,\s/, $list);
    }
    close $fh;
}

my %go_terms;
open my $go, '<', 'file4';

while (<$go>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $terms) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    $go_terms{$id} = $terms =~ tr/,//dr;
}
close $go;

my %output;

for my $file (@files) {
    for my $id (keys %ids) {
        my $count = ($data{$file1}{$id} * $data{$file}{$id})->size;
        my $percent = sprintf "%.0f", 100 * $count / $data{$file1}{$id}->size;

        $output{$id}{$file} = [$count, $percent];   
    }   
}

for my $id (keys %ids) {
    my $count = ($data{$file1}{$id} * $data{$files[0]}{$id} * $data{$files[1]}{$id})->size;
    my $percent = sprintf "%.0f", 100 * $count / $data{$file1}{$id}->size;

    $output{$id}{all_files} = [$count, $percent];
}

# output saved as f2.csv
print join(",", qw/ID   f1f2_overlap   f1f2_%overlap
                        f1f3_overlap   f1f3_%overlap
                      f1f2f3_overlap f1f2f3_%overlap Go_terms/), "\n";

for my $id (keys %output) {
    print "$id,";

    for my $file (@files, 'all_files') {
        my $aref = $output{$id}{$file};
        print join(",", @$aref), ",";   
    }
    print +($go_terms{$id} // ''), "\n";
}
```

The Excel sheet looks like this.

[image]